# ath10k (QCA9377) firmware still keeps crashing on E200HA

Tags: wireless, firmware

Recently my wifi has started dropping at random times.  I've looked for answers and tried:

using the original firmware drivers from the install disk

using the latest firmware drivers from github

using the firmware drivers from ubuntu 16.04LTS

using a different browser

every different combination of board.bin, board-2.bin, firmware-5.bin and firmware-6.bin, old and new versions

setting a static ip address,

a complete reinstall of Ubuntu

yet the problem won't go away.  I didn't have this problem when the machine had Windows 10 on it, nor for the first couple of years with ubuntu.

Also the output of ping varies - sometimes it's "network is unreachable", sometimes "Destination host unreachable"

Sometimes I get a question mark in the taskbar, sometimes a blank space, but it can still detect the network.

Please help before I launch the laptop into the ether and go back to Windows.

```
wilbur@wilbur-E200HA:~$ sudo lshw -class network
[sudo] password for wilbur: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: wlp1s0
       version: 31
       serial: f0:03:8c:a2:28:59
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.2.0+ firmware=WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 ip=192.168.1.6 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:133 memory:91200000-913fffff
```

...

```
wilbur@wilbur-E200HA:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2b31]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

Comment: By way of update - seems this only happens when on battery, never when it's on mains power.  Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I'm also having this issue. But only when charger connected (Ubuntu 23 with kernel 6.2.0)

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

I disabled the wifi power management and the problem hasn't recurred since.

In /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf I changed the line

wifi.powersave = 3

to

wifi.powersave = 2

No connections dropped since.